# Adding custom package to buildroot

Tags: c, linux, makefile, shared-libraries, buildroot

Someone can help me to write an **.mk** file and add custom library to buildroot.

Example:

I have foo.c and foo.h and this library that i wrote, have to be installed on a custom Linux to make my main app running successfully.

I also want to know if until this Linux was deployed, Could I use <foo.h> instead of ".../foo.h"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you have a simple library with a .c and .h.

The Makefile needs to do the following.

1. Compile the .c to a .o
2. Put the .o inside a .a (Static library).
3. Put the .a (static library) into the "build root" as you call it. If the "prefix/build root" chosen is /usr/local (the default in most cases) the correct place is /usr/local/lib.
4. Copy the .h to the "build root". The correct place is "include". "/usr/local/include".

You can see a simple Makefile example [here](https://github.com/harkaitz/c-miniauth). Also you can make the project a single header project. Like [here](https://github.com/harkaitz/c-ftemplate)